# foreach access empty value from input field

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

```
<input class="select2" name="{{$section['id']}}[]" data-placeholder="Select a State" style="width: 100%;">
```

```
foreach ($data["{$section['id']}"] as $value) { 
    if (!empty($value)) {     
        code......

    }
}
```

there is 8 input field with the same name attribute but if I fill only 3 fields then (Undefined offset: 4) this error shows I know that foreach access 4 field value but it is empty how to solve this problenm

Comment: what actually is the name of these inputs?

Comment: you can simply `dd($data)` to check what you're getting and debug a little

Comment: you probably need to be using isset($value)

Comment: all these input has same input name="{{$section['id']}}[]"

Comment: array:11 [▼
  "_token" => "PqMBAoZhhOjw9kUe11YlFnO9JA80GxFaboCLkSKK"
  "FRONTEND" => "1"
  "BACKEND" => "2"
  "DATABASE" => "3"
  "DESIGN" => "4"
  "MOBILE" => "5"
  "STRUCTURES" => "6"
  "TESTING" => "7"
  "BLOCKCHAIN" => "8"
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "JavaScript"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "PHP"
    1 => "Laravel"
  ]
]  here is the input of dd($data)